# How to create a Kafka topics on a SASL enabled Zookeeper?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, jaas, sasl

We have a kafka cluster and are in the process of locking down the specific nodes based on these standards:  https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/zookeeper-acls/content/zookeeper_acls_best_practices_kafka.html

Once we lock down the /broker/topics node with SASL:kafka:cdrwa, we are unable to use the kafka-topics.sh tool to create topics.  We tried using these tools on the broker, which has the correct KafkaClient in the jaas file, but it appears zookeeper treats the cmd tools as a separate client.  We are experiencing the same thing when locking down /kafka-acls and using the kafka-acls.sh tool.

How can we pass our jaas file in the command line tools?

UPDATE
Here are the contents of the jaas file (passwords removed). Both the tools and the broker exist on the same machine.  The broker is not having issue authenticating with zookeeper.

```
KafkaServer {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="---";
};

KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
  username="controlcenter"
  password="---";
};

Client {
  org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="---";
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does simple environment setting not work?

```
$ export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<your_jaas.conf>"
$ kafka-topics --create ...
```

Comment: We have that variable set and it works for the broker but the tools don't appear to be using this variable.

Comment: Could you please update the question with your jaas.conf's content? Should work...

Comment: I added the jaas config

Comment: And I assume `controlcenter` entity has already been created in ZK. What error are you getting, and is there anything interesting in zk log?

Comment: The environment variable was the key.  Typo on our jaas location. Thanks!

Comment: glad you found it, those are the worst! :)